# Jenkins - Angular Build Error Message

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-integration

Trying to set up CI for an Angular project with Jenkins.

Trying to get Jenkins to generate a build using the following (after cloning down the repo into the workspace)

```
ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false && cpy ./server.js ./dist
```

Jenkins however gives me the following error

> wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file in
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Angular CI@tmp/durable-f993c6f2
>   (JENKINS-48300: if on a laggy filesystem, consider
>   -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=300)

I do not have much experience with Jenkins or setting up servers for CI in general and a Google of the message hasn't provided much clarity.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

(can post more code if needed)

Thanks!

Comment: Based on what I read about this error, I have few questions, 1. Where is the build being run? Master or Slave. 2. Can you try whats being recommended in the error logs? Changing the heartbeat value?

Comment: Here is what I have been reading: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48300?focusedCommentId=330340&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-330340

Comment: Few more material: https://web.archive.org/web/20141227025217/http://tupilabs.com/2014/06/13/durable-tasks-in-jenkins.html

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on a java build.   I made the recommended adjustment to the heartbeat time but that didn't resolve it.   Then, I hit this [thread](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50379?focusedCommentId=347496&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-347496) and upgrading the Jenkins DurableTask plugin resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Java -process was taking 22% of the memory of the executor machine, causing other processes to swap.

Solution 1): Restart Jenkins to free up memory and prevent swapping.

Solution 2): From Manage Jenkins -> Script Console add:

System.setProperty("org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL", "36000")